# Setting OnClickListeners for Dynamically added views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamic, android-widget

I am adding a small view to a linearlayout. I have to apply a `View.OnClickListener` to it, but even though the view has been added, the `onClick` still does not fire. Here's my method

```
for (Streams stream : streamArray) {
streamCount++;
    if (!(streamCount > 3)) {
    // ADD AN ITEM
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.stream_item, theLinearLayoutforStreamItems, false);
    //SET ONCLICK

    v.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("onclick", ""+position );
            }
        });

    txtStreamItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtViewStream_item);
    txtStreamItem.setText(stream.name);
    theLinearLayoutforStreamItems.addView(v);

}
```

The `onClick()`does not fire. I do not know why, and I cannot find any thing on the internet on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want to achieve is:

```
txtStreamItem.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("onclick", ""+position );
        }
    });
```

Put it just below this line:

```
txtStreamItem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtViewStream_item);
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. I think it was more of a logic problem than an SDK problem.

Comment: `View v` is a container. It contain `TextView`, this is what you really want to access.

Answer (score 0):

Set `View.setClickable` & `focus-able true`.